# Generar en textbox una fecha calculada sumando campo DIAS y FECHA ACTUAL

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un sistema de multas en el cual se deben colocar los días de multas y la fecha en que inicia y termina dicha multa, ocurre que al colocarse los días en un campo separado puede pasar que ese numero de días no concuerde con las fechas de inicio y termino, pasando algo así:

Fecha de inicio 23/2/17 días de multa 4 fecha de termino 29/2/17

Quisiera que en mi sistema la fecha de inicio fuera siempre la actual, y que la fecha de termino se calculara sumando los días que insertaron en el campo días, tomando en cuenta que los días empiezan a contar al día siguiente de la fecha de multa es decir.

Si te multan el 23/2/17 y te dan 3 días, seria: 24, 25 y 26, por lo tanto fecha de termino seria: 26-2-17.

Por otro lado quisiera poder guardar ambas fechas en mi base de datos, porque a veces el formato guarda diferente al que es MySQL

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h1>Indique los datos de la multa</h1>

<label>Ingrese fecha de inicio</label>
<input type="text" name="fecha_inicio" value="<?=$fecha_fin=date('d-m-Y');?>">

<br>
<label>Ingrese los días de arresto</label>
<input type="text" name="dias_arresto">

<br>
<label>Ingrese fecha de termino</label>
<input type="text" name="fecha_inicio" value="">

<br>

<input type="submit" value="procesar">
<?php
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve investigando y encontre la solucion para sumar dias a la fecha y que se autogener, ademas de un boton para restablecer la sumatoria, ya que esta se bloquea para evitar que la cambien una vez calculada:

**obtener_fechaactual.js**

```
function fechaAtual() { 
    var fecha_actual = new Date() 
    var dia = fecha_actual.getDate() 
    var mes = fecha_actual.getMonth() + 1 
    var anio = fecha_actual.getFullYear() 

    if (mes < 10) 
        mes = '0' + mes 

    if (dia < 10) 
        dia = '0' + dia 
    return (dia + "/" + mes + "/" + anio) 
} 

function MostrarFechaA() {
   document.omd.fecha_inicio.value =  fechaAtual();
}
```

**obtener_fechatermino.js**

```
function MostrarFechaT() {
 var d = document.getElementById('dias').value;
 if (d==0){
    alert("No has ingresado el numero de dias")
    var fechaFinal="";
    throw new FatalError();
 }else{
 var Fecha = new Date();
 var sFecha = fecha || (Fecha.getDate() + "/" + (Fecha.getMonth() +1) + "/" + Fecha.getFullYear());
 var sep = sFecha.indexOf('/') != -1 ? '/' : '-'; 
 var aFecha = sFecha.split(sep);
 var fecha = aFecha[2]+'/'+aFecha[1]+'/'+aFecha[0];
 fecha= new Date(fecha);
 fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+parseInt(d));
 var anno=fecha.getFullYear();
 var mes= fecha.getMonth()+1;
 var dia= fecha.getDate();
 mes = (mes < 10) ? ("0" + mes) : mes;
 dia = (dia < 10) ? ("0" + dia) : dia;
 var fechaFinal = (dia+sep+mes+sep+anno);
document.getElementById("fecha_termino").value=fechaFinal;
document.getElementById("dias").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("restablecer").hidden=false;
} 
}

function Restablecer() {
document.getElementById("fecha_termino").value="";
document.getElementById("dias").value="";
document.getElementById("dias").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("restablecer").hidden=true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="funciones/obtener_fechaactual.js"></script>
  <script src="funciones/obtener_fechatermino.js"></script>
 <tr>
   <td>Dias: </td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="dias" onblur="MostrarFechaT()" id="dias">
   <input type="button" onclick="Restablecer()" id="restablecer" value="Cambiar" hidden>
   </td>
   <td><p><STRONG>NOTA:</STRONG>
   Las fechas de la OMD se calcularan automaticamente, despues de ingresar el n&uacute;mero de d&iacute;as.</p>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Fecha de inicio: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="fecha_inicio" readonly id="fecha_inicio" disabled></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Fecha de termino: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="fecha_termino" readonly id="fecha_termino"></td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas se puede solucionar con javascript, para generar la fecha y después con php (supongo) para guardar en mysql.

Este código va a agregar una función a todas las variables del tipo Date ya que estamos usando el prototype y también si haces esto ya esta manejado el cambio de mes o año, por ejemplo si le sumas 2 días a 31/10, entonces será 2/11.

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}
```

Puedes crear un listener como un 'on change' cuando seleccionan la fecha de inicio, después creas el objecto Date:

```
    var startDate = new Date();
```

Y cuando agreguen los días de arresto llamas la función:

```
    var newDate = startDate.addDays(numero_de_dias_a_agregar)
```

De esta forma ya tendrás en tu nueva variable newDate el valor de la fecha mas el numero de días que quieres. Ahora nadamas le pones el valor de esa fecha al campo de fecha termino.

Ahora el otro tema es cuando mandas al back los datos, crea variables del tipo date de PHP, docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, y en el MySql utiliza el tipo de campo de timestamp, docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html, con eso puedes guardar tu variable de PHP en MySql. Si haces esto el formato no cambiara porque es un Datestamp o Timestamp, y cuando saques datos de tu base mysql podras crear un objeto Date en PHP.

Si tienes duda me avisas!
Saludos!